# Taylor Expansion of the Polynomial in Flajolet’s Fundamental Lemma

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics, taylor-expansion, algebraic-combinatorics

I am currently looking at [the proof of Flajolet’s Fundamental Lemma](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2017/09/lattice_paths_and_continued_fr.html). Before I phrase the question, I need to review the definition of $(0,k)$-path and define its weight.

Define **$(0,k)$-path** as the following ($k\ge 0$):

1. It is a lattice path that start with $(0,0)\in \mathbb{N}^{2}$ ($0\in \mathbb{N}$).
2. For each step, it can go one unit, at either diagonally upper-right, diagonally down-right, or horizontally right direction.
3. It cannot go below $y=0$ or above $y=k$.
4. It ends at $(l,0)$, for some $l\ge 0$.

Let $P_{0}^{k}$ be the collection of all such $(0,k)$-paths. Let's define the **weight** on on each path as the following:

1. For each step diagonally upper-right or down-right, associate it with weight $1$.
2. For each step horizontally right at level $\not= k$, associate it with weight the indeterminant $z+1$. For step horizontally right at level $k$, associate it with weight $0$.
3. For the trivial path, the single point $(0,0)$ (i.e. $l=0$), define its weight as $1$.
4. Define the weight of the entire path, $\sigma$, as the product of the weight of all of its steps, which is a polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[z]$. Denote it by $\omega(\sigma)$.

Let's consider the sum of the weight of all $(0,k)$-paths, i.e. define
$$
p_{0}^{k}:=\sum_{\sigma\in P_{0}^{k}} \omega(\sigma)
$$
which is a formal power series in $\mathbb{Z}[[z]]$.
It can be proven that
$$
p_{0}^{k}=\frac{1}{-z-\frac{1}{-z-\frac{1}{\frac{\vdots}{-z-1}}}} 
$$
which has $k$-layers. I notice that its Taylor expansion at $z=0$ always has integer coefficient, for all $k\ge 1$. For example
$$
p_{0}^{2}=1+2x+3x^{2}+5x^{3}+8x^{4}+13x^{5}+21x^{6}+\cdots
$$

**My questions is this: I understand that the entire polynomial $p_{0}^{k}$ is counting the total weight of all $(0,k)$-paths, for all length $l\ge 0$. But what is the geometric intepretation of the coefficients of its Taylor expansion? What objects are they counting?**

Initially, I guessed that, for $p_{0}^{k}$, the coefficient of $x^{l}$ is counting the weighted number of paths ends at $(l,0)$. However, it is not the case, but I feel that it is counting something like that.

Comment: For $p_0^2$, as far as I see,  these coefficients are consecutive Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: @AlexRavsky Yeah! I also noticed this, but I am curious on whether these Fibonacci numbers are actually counting something, or it is just a coincidence.

Comment: Have you tried to look at those paths as some kind of Laguerre histories?

Comment: I'm sorry, is it properly defined? It seems to me that there are infinite paths of weight $1$ that go like (upright, downring). There's no way you sum them up and get $[z^0] p_0^2 = 1$? You probably want $a_i$, $b_j$ and $c_k$ to be actual formal variables to make it converge...

Comment: @OleksandrKulkov Thanks for your comments! Yeah, originally, the author in the article [link](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2017/09/lattice_paths_and_continued_fr.html) uses the formal variable $a_{i},b_{j},c_{k}$ and proved its convergence. I am currently considering a special case where I plug in $a_{i}=b_{j}=1$, for all $i,j$, and $c_{i}=z+1$ for $i\not=k$ and $c_{k}=0$.

Comment: Welp, the problem is that with these substitutions it no longer converges, and thus kind of loses its connection to the original formulation. That is, $p_0^k$ is still well-defined as a continued fraction, but not as a sum over $\sigma \in P_0^k$.